# Need to store data in two dimentional array dynamically

Tags: jquery

I want to store the table row details dynamically in an array.The last column of every row having the edit button .if i click the edit button it has to pick that particular row details.Explain me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Jquery here. You don't have to save the whole table data for this. I'm sure you are creating the table dynamically(as you don't have the data in an array already).

Do indexing, provide class/id or any data attribute of the  tag with a unique id(index) for each row.

```
    <tr class="1">
        <td class="name">Harry</td>
        <td class="edit">
            <input type="button" name="btnedit">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2">
        <td class="name">Ron</td>
        <td class="edit">
            <input type="button" name="btnedit">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When a user clicks EDIT button, find the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [closest](https://api.jquery.com/?s=closest)  with the help of jquery and now can access the row data by "tr.classname td.classname".

Jquery code to get button click-

```
$('input[name="btnedit"]').click(function(){ CODE });
```

Please search for the rest of the code. Let me know if you are stuck.